# How to redirect if rewrite_module is not available?

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis-6, url-rewrite-module

I am working on a codeigniter project on which I don't have privilege to change configuration, so I can't enable rewrite engine.

On another case, instead apache, I am using IIS 6.0.

So, how to redirect the pages in both cases so I could make the system work without index.php on url ?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: You're almost asking "How do I swim without liquid around me?". The rewrite_module is required, and you _should_ have access to it, if not get it.

Comment: @husk - pity IIS7 has a url rewriting module that you can install and configure. If you can change your IIS6 install you could use http://www.isapirewrite.com/ whcih is an ISAPI filter.

Answer (score 1):

Without the rewrite engine, you're stuck with ugly URLs. You can do something like this though:

```
/index.php/your/nicer/url
```

That should work on any server, with most software.

Comment: Yeah, that works, and I am searching for method to remove index.php

Comment: You can't without using mod_rewrite or equivalent for IIS.

Comment: by default your index document is triggered from document_root would that not mean you could ismply remove index.php from that URI?
 //your/nicer/url (note the double slashes)

Comment: @IesusSonesson No, every server I'm aware of would resolve that to a single slash.